# How to draw a freehand line using pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I want to draw resistance and support lines by hand, import them to pine script, and calculate the distance(percentage) of the current value of the price and the drawn line(support or resistance).

I couldn't find the solution on the internet. Anyone helps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in `pinescript`. User drawn objects are not accessible.

As a workaround, you can have a user input where you can enter your support/resistance level manually.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could we draw a trendline using pinescript between two user input resistance/support Level?

Comment: Yes, with some maths, you can do that.